# Spring data elasticSearch returns null with findOne

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm testing Spring data with elasticSearch. The ES server is running on a remote server in tha same room.

I have one index created a day, under an alias. I'm trying to find a simple tweet. But when I try a `findOne()`, it doesn't seem to work because it returns always `null`.

Also, `findAll(ids)` doesn't work because I'm using the alias, but I can't find in the documentation how to handle this.

**What do I want to achieve  ?**

For the moment, simply retrieve a tweet with a given `id_str`.
The count method works, the findOne doesn't

**Here are my questions**
What should I do to make `findOne()` to work ?
Which way should I use to search on multiple indexes in this alias ?

**Here is how the datas looks like in ES**

```
{
    "id_str" : "135131315100051",
    "..." : "...",
    "user" : {
        "id_str" : "15843643228"
        "..." : "..."
    }
}
```

**My model**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Document(indexName = "alias", type = "tweets")
public class Tweet
{
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String idStr;

    public String getIdStr()
    {
        return idStr;
    }

    public void setIdStr(final String idStr)
    {
        this.idStr = idStr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "{ id_str : " + idStr + " }";
    }
}
```

Alias is `alias`, and indexes are `alias_dd-mm-yyyy`

**My repository**

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import com.thales.communications.osintlab.bigdata.webservices.models.Tweet;

public interface EsTweetRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Tweet, String>
{
    Tweet findByIdStr(String idStr);
}
```

**My test**

```
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnATweet()
    {

        //lets try to search same record in elasticsearch
        final Tweet tweet1 = tweetRepository.findOne("593768150975512576");
        //final Tweet tweet = tweetRepository.findByIdStr("593897683661824000");
        System.out.println("Count is " + tweet1);
        //System.out.println("Count is " + tweetRepository.count());
        //      System.out.println(tweet.toString());
    }
```

Of course, the tweet with the tested Id exists :). And the `count()` is working fine.

Thanks for your help

---

**EDIT**

Here is a sample application of what I have : https://github.com/ogdabou/es-stackoverflow-sample

It seems that spring-data-elasticsearch is look for the field "_id" and not the field "id_str". Maybe because of method parsing (look [there](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)). I'm looking for a way to bind my json "id_str" attribute to my idStr java model.

Comment: can you create sample application like https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application and share so that it will be easy to understand what you are trying to achieve ? also your mapping has user object but your entity class does not !

Comment: Hi, I'll try to make one monday or tuesday (i'm in internship part-time). Thank you anyway

Comment: @MohsinHusen A lot of items present in the mapping are not present on my model class, is it a problem ? I succeeded only with the id and a name field when I started to learn ES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What was the real issue**

We set the `_id` field of our tweet in Elasticsearch with the `id` field given by twitter. But it saves it in another format ( eg 132 becomes 1.32E2)
When I'm going a `findOne()` it is searching for a match with the Elasticsearch `_id` field and not the `id_str` I needed.

**Solution**

[There](https://github.com/ogdabou/es-stackoverflow-sample), you have 2 commits, the first is the issue, the second the solution.

New repository

```
public interface EsTweetRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Tweet, String>
{
    @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"term\" : {\"id_str\" : \"?0\"}}}}")
    Tweet findByIdStr(String idStr);
}
```

The model

```
@Document(indexName = "my_index_01", type = "tweets")
public class Tweet
{
    // Elasticsearch object internal id. Look at field "_id"
    @Id
    private String id;

    // Twitter internal id, saved under the "id_str" field
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String id_str;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String text;

    public String getId_str()
    {
        return id_str;
    }

    public void setId_str(final String id_str)
    {
        this.id_str = id_str;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(final String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "{ _id : " + id + ", id_str :  " + id_str + ", text : " + text + " }";
    }
}
```